# apk command to find which package installs a program? [Alpine Linux]

Tags: package-management, packages, alpine

I want to install program `/usr/bin/time` using Alpine Linux package manager `apk` (`time` is a program runtime measurement tool). But I don't know which package to install. `apk search time` reports 147 matches.
**How do I narrow down `apk search` to a particular program path?**

I would like to `apk search --command=/usr/bin/time`. But `apk search` does not provide this option.

Is there some Linux command-line magic that could help? Or a different package querying tool?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307167/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-apk-packages